# Randomly select 50% of records from 3 different groups for A/B test

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Apologies if this has been asked already. I am trying to setup a small A/B test and split the records evenly (50%) across 3 categories: `Low intent`, `Medium intent`, `High intent`. I'd like to randomly select 50% of each of the 3 categories to a control group and 50% to a treatment group to another column.

Sample Data:

```
|ID|Buyer Intent  |Email
:--:|:-----------:|:-------------|
|1  |Low Intent   |john@gmail.com|
|2  |Medium Intent|jane@gmail.com|
|3  |Medium Intent|tom@gmail.com |
|4  |Low Intent   |sara@gmail.com|
|5  |High Intent  |mich@gmail.com|
|6  |High Intent  |sall@gmail.com|
```

Desired Data:

```
|ID|Buyer Intent |Email           |Group
:--|:-----------:|:--------------:|:----------:|
|1 |Low Intent   |john@gmail.com  |Control     |
|2 |Medium Intent|jane@gmail.com  |Treatment   |
|3 |Medium Intent|tom@gmail.com   |Control     |
|4 |Low Intent   |sara@gmail.com  |Treatment.  |
|5 |High Intent  |mich@gmail.com  |Treatment.  |
|6 |High Intent  |sall@gmail.com  | Control.   |
```

Comment: Thank you for the data. Please provide it in a format that is easier to copy and paste into a program, such as `df.head().to_dict('list')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`groupby.sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sample.html) to choose 50% records per group and then assign the labels with [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
control = df.groupby('Buyer Intent').sample(frac=0.5).index

df['Group'] = np.where(df.index.isin(control), 'Control', 'Treatment')

#    ID   Buyer Intent           Email      Group
# 0   1     Low Intent  john@gmail.com    Control
# 1   2  Medium Intent  jane@gmail.com    Control
# 2   3  Medium Intent   tom@gmail.com  Treatment
# 3   4     Low Intent  sara@gmail.com  Treatment
# 4   5    High Intent  mich@gmail.com    Control
# 5   6    High Intent  sall@gmail.com  Treatment
```

---

Note that [`groupby.sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sample.html) already randomizes:

> Return a random sample of items from each group.

But to shuffle explicitly, you can add [`DataFrame.sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) with `frac=1`:

```
# shuffle df
df = df.sample(frac=1)

# same as before
control = df.groupby('Buyer Intent').sample(frac=0.5).index
df['Group'] = np.where(df.index.isin(control), 'Control', 'Treatment')
```

---

If you don't have [`groupby.sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sample.html) (pandas < 1.1.0):

- Try [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html) + [`DataFrame.sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html):

  ```
  control = df.groupby('Buyer Intent').apply(lambda g: g.sample(frac=0.5))
  df['Group'] = np.where(df.index.isin(control), 'Control', 'Treatment')
  ```
- Or [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html) + [`np.random.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html):

  ```
  control = df.groupby('Buyer Intent').apply(lambda g: np.random.choice(g.index, int(len(g)/2)))
  df['Group'] = np.where(df.index.isin(control), 'Control', 'Treatment')
  ```

Comment: Is there a way to randomize the selection. The data might be in some order and I would like to ensure the group is randomly selected. Can I use numpy.random.shuffle?

Comment: I'm seeing an AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'sample' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method. What might be a work around here? Thanks

Comment: @RyanDan what's your `pd.__version__`? `groupby.sample` was introduced in version 1.1.0 (July 2020), so it sounds like yours is older. are you able to update?

Comment: @RyanDan i posted a workaround with `groupby.apply`, but i'd still recommend updating if possible

Comment: Thanks for the work around. The np.random.choice worked for the first part, but for making the "Group" column I'm only getting "Treatment" for the Group instead of a random mix of control and treatment. Do you know how to fix this? Thanks much appreciated.

Comment: @RyanDan try adding `.explode()` to the end of the 1st part (and then rerun 2nd part): `control = df.groupby('Buyer Intent').apply(lambda g: np.random.choice(g.index, int(len(g)/2))).explode()`

Comment: if that still doesn't work, i suspect it's a version issue (please post `pd.__version__` and `np.__version__`) or example issue (some subtle-but-significant difference between the minimal example vs real data)

Comment: @RyanDan did this end up working for you?

Comment: Yep. I was able to update pandas and the initial way worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. To choose 50% you have to use something that is to return a random sample of items from each group, this thing is called "groupby.sample".
2. Next you need something to return chosen items depending on the condition, this thing is called np.where.